# Adding list from two methods in c#

Tags: c#, list, addition

I am trying to add List of getRecords2 with list of getRecords. For some reason on getRecords, it takes a long time to process and times out when I call it.

```
public static List<ListA> getRecords2(string id)
{
   List<ListA> listOfRecords = new List<ListA>();
   using (SqlConnection con = SqlConnect.GetDBConnection())
   {
      con.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandText = "sp2";
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));

      SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      while (reader.Read())
      {
         ListA listMember = new ListA();
         listMember.ID = (int)reader["ID"];
     listMember.Name = reader["FullName"].ToString().Trim();
      }
      con.Close();
    }
       return listOfRecords;
  }

  public static List<ListA> getRecords(string id)
  {
     List<ListA> listOfRecords = new List<ListA>();
     using (SqlConnection con = SqlConnect.GetDBConnection())
     {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "sp1";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
           ListA listMember = new ListA();
           listMember.ID = (int)reader["ID"];
           listMember.Name = reader["FullName"].ToString().Trim();
        }
        con.Close();
      }
      List<ListA> newlist = getRecords(id);
      foreach (ListA x in newlist) listOfRecords.Add(x);
      return listOfRecords;
   }
```

I add the list of getRecords in getRecords2. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You have recursive call here `List<ListA> newlist = getRecords(id);`

Comment: It looks like getRecords is calling itself?

Comment: @JakeP and lazyberezovsky... thank you so much guys...just needed couple of extra pairs of eyes to fix my problem... lol... i think i need a break

Comment: If I were you, I'd open up the [Debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging), and see which area of that code is taking the most time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you're not adding anything to your list within `while(reader.Read())` loop. `Add` method call is missing on both `GetRecords` and `GetRecords2`:

```
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ListA listMember = new ListA();

        listMember.ID = (int)reader["ID"];
        listMember.Name = reader["FullName"].ToString().Trim();

        // you have to add this line:
        listOfRecords.Add(listMember);
    }
```

And another problem: you're calling `getRecords(id)` over and over:

```
List<ListA> newlist = getRecords(id);
foreach (ListA x in newlist) listOfRecords.Add(x);
```

should be:

```
List<ListA> newlist = getRecords2(id);
foreach (ListA x in newlist) listOfRecords.Add(x);
```

And last but not least: you don't have to call `con.Close();` - it will be done automatically when program flow exits `using` block, as a part of `Dispose` method.